# How to detect changes of nested property initialized with variables

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection

I have two components, parent and child. In the parent component I have an object like so:

```
firstCondition = false;
secondCondition = false;
filters: Filters = {
    dropdowns: [
        { label: 'Direction', options: { disabled: this.firstCondition || this.secondCondition }
    ]
}
```

My child component takes the `filters` object as `@Input` like so:

```
@Input() f: Filters
```

Whenever the value of either `firstCondition` or `secondCondition` changes I want Angular's change detection to detect this change in value, but it doesn't...
If I were to do the following in the parent component it would work as expected:

```
this.filters.dropdowns[0].options.disabled = !this.filters.dropdowns[0].options.disabled
```

I think the problem is that I don't change the value of `disabled` directly, but indirectly. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: i think you never update the value of `disabled: `  as this code is evaluated only at the component creation. you should react to properties chaged with at least `this.filters.dropdowns[0].options.disabled = this.firstCondition || this.secondCondition`

Comment: @Andrei you are absolutely right. Thank you for making me realize this!